# Chrome doesn't translate sites when I disable javascript

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to use website translation, but disable javascript on them. But when I disable javascript, Chrome cannot translate the sites.Tell me how can I fix this? I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome windows 10.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome uses javascript for the translation feature.
I couldn't find an official statement from google that state the use of javascript.

Using the extension [NoScript](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/noscript/doojmbjmlfjjnbmnoijecmcbfeoakpjm) shows that chrome injects a javascript file, when it detects a language that isn't the system default which tries to contact
*translate.googleapis.com*

Either you allow javscript for this domain/file or you can't use the translation feature.

[image: NoScript-Panel when visiting https://cnnespanol.cnn.com/]